# Moq Intercept FactoryMock New Instance

Tags: .net, moq, xunit

I have a Factory class with a Create method returning IFoo objects. I created a FactoryMock class that implements the interface as virtual methods and returns IFoo mocks setup with basic functions. So far so good.

If the method under test returns IFoo, everything is good, IFoo gets created and used, and I can ensure it was used properly.

If the method under test does not return IFoo, however, how can I intercept the IFoo object that was created from the factory?

I could do something like this... but can I access the CallBase return value from the Callback?

```
var factory = new Mock<FactoryMock>() { CallBase = true };
factory.Setup(x => x.Create).CallBase().Callback(() => ...);
```

Another option would be to add a LastCreated property to FactoryMock. What's the recommended approach for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no response, I found an easy way to solve it. In FactoryMock, I simply add a public property "public List Instances" that contains all instances created by the factory. Then I can easily access those instances, and I can use FactoryMock directly without wrapping Moq around it; but return the IFoo objects as Moq types. Not sure if others are doing it this way, but that's good enough for me.

EDIT: I'm realizing I'm doing Unit Testing wrong. In this scenario, I'm focusing on "how it is done" instead of the end result, and actually I'm breaking most of the best practices. If someone is asking the same question, this is a good document about best practices for conducting tests. Now need to rewrite everything :)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices